# In Place Windows Server 2008 Standard R2 to Enterprise 2008 R2 w/ SQL Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server

Need to do an in place upgrade of a Standard 2008 R2 Server to Enterprise 2008 R2 that has SQL Server running on it.

Anyone have any experiences/issues with this process? I've done this process on server without SQL.

I have considered a format/redeploy/restore, so looking for input on just the above technical situation.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you changing the edition of SQL Server as well, or just changing the edition of Windows Server?

Comment: just windows, not sql itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine doing the in-place upgrade.  I've done it with no problems.  In general, though, I still prefer to do clean installs on any production server in lieu of an in-place upgrade.  A Windows upgrade is different than doing an in-place SQL upgrade, though.  I will always do a clean install of SQL instead of an upgrade.

That said, you don't mention what version and edition of SQL Server you're running.  Have a look at [**this Technet article**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx) for the SQL OS support matrix.